# Pull metadata from a soundcloud account with over 1500 tracks

Tags: python, api, soundcloud

I'm helping out someone who needs to pull metadata from their soundcloud account (track title, description, date published, size, duration, media URL, etc). Unfortunately, they have over 1500+ tracks, so it is not sufficient to use the rss feed, which is limited to 200 or 250 tracks.

soundcloud no longer gives out client ID for their API. I found a client ID used in a github project. Then using soundcloud python wrapper found here https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python, I tried to get track meta data with this

```
 import soundcloud

 client = soundcloud.Client(client_id=CLIENT_ID_REDACTED)
 tracks = client.get('/users/9999999/tracks/', limit=5000)
 print(len(tracks))
```

Alas, it will only return max 200 tracks, so that doesn't help.

Does this 200 track limit exist if I have an actual client ID registered to the account?  Is there any hope of getting this data?

thanks in advance

Comment: After 200 tracks, do you get an error? Or does the script keep running, but nothing new gets returned?

Comment: It only returns 200 results. The request returns an array with 200 items. No error.

Answer (score 1):

Add ?linked_partitioning=1 to the initial request and the response will contain a property called next_href which gives you the URL of the next page of results.

Answer (score 0):

linked_partitioning is the key. Thanks to @nickf

Btw, the soundcloud API doc is either wrong or refers to an old API

```
import soundcloud

client = soundcloud.Client(client_id='clientidhere')

page_size = 200

# get first page of tracks
tracks = client.get('/users/999999/tracks', limit=page_size,
    linked_partitioning=1)

c = 1

for track in tracks.collection:
    print(c,track.title)
    c += 1

# .next_href exists means there are more pages
while hasattr(tracks, 'next_href'):
    # pass .next_href to get next page
    tracks = client.get(tracks.next_href, limit=page_size,
        linked_partitioning=1)
    for track in tracks.collection:
        print(c,track.title)
        c += 1
```